# Livewire quantity input field not update dynamically when change value

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, product-quantity, livewires

I've purchased pos software which is not updated the quantity input field when changed into the checkout page it's working with a button. I want to change form submit button quantity input to dynamic input field with cart total, not with a hard-coded button.
[Screenshot of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltNIn.jpg)

Blade Code

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="updateQuantity('{{ $cart_item->rowId }}', '{{ $cart_item->id }}')">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input wire:model.lazy="quantity.{{ $cart_item->id }}" style="min-width: 40px;max-width: 90px;" type="number" class="form-control" value="{{ $cart_item->qty }}" min="1">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update function

```
public function updateQuantity($row_id, $product_id) {
    if ($this->check_quantity[$product_id] < $this->quantity[$product_id]) {
        session()->flash('message', 'The requested quantity is not available in stock.');
        return;
    }

    Cart::instance($this->cart_instance)->update($row_id, $this->quantity[$product_id]);

    $cart_item = Cart::instance($this->cart_instance)->get($row_id);

    Cart::instance($this->cart_instance)->update($row_id, [
        'options' => [
            'sub_total'             => $cart_item->price * $cart_item->qty,
            'code'                  => $cart_item->options->code,
            'stock'                 => $cart_item->options->stock,
            'unit'                  => $cart_item->options->unit,
            'product_tax'           => $cart_item->options->product_tax,
            'unit_price'            => $cart_item->options->unit_price,
            'product_discount'      => $cart_item->options->product_discount,
            'product_discount_type' => $cart_item->options->product_discount_type,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Use a lifecycle-hook (the "updated" one) to intercept changes to the property, and run your handler from there https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: @Qirel can you give code example please